# How to fix Rails 6.0.0.beta1 directory already being watched error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

I have a new rails app running Rails 6.0.0.beta1 and I'm getting this error when I run any `rails` command such as `rails s`, `rails test`, `rails db:migrate` etc.:

```
** ERROR: directory is already being watched! *
```

I also get it when running `bundle exec guard`

I've been googling this error quite a bit and can't figure out what's causing it. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Here's a full trace of the error:

rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0.beta1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
        ** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

```
    Directory: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/.bin/compression-webpack-plugin

    is already being watched through: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin

    MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
    ** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

    Directory: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/.bin/mini-css-extract-plugin

    is already being watched through: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin

    MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
    ** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

    Directory: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/.bin/compression-webpack-plugin

    is already being watched through: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin

    MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
    ** ERROR: directory is already being watched! **

    Directory: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/@rails/webpacker/node_modules/.bin/mini-css-extract-plugin

    is already being watched through: /Users/lee/Documents/Code/dashboard/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin

    MORE INFO: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Duplicate-directory-errors
```

And, here's my Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

# Rails 6
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.beta1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'webpacker', '>= 4.0.0.rc.3'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# App Specific gems
gem 'clearance'
gem 'pundit'

# Development and test
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'capybara-email'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And my Guardfile:

```
# Defines the matching rules for Guard.
guard :minitest, spring: "bin/rails test", all_on_start: false do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)/?(.*)_test\.rb$})
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { 'test' }
  watch('config/routes.rb')    { integration_tests }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.*?)\.rb$}) do |matches|
    "test/models/#{matches[1]}_test.rb"
  end
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*?)_controller\.rb$}) do |matches|
    resource_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/([^/]*?)/.*\.html\.erb$}) do |matches|
    ["test/controllers/#{matches[1]}_controller_test.rb"] +
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*?)_helper\.rb$}) do |matches|
    integration_tests(matches[1])
  end
  watch('app/views/layouts/application.html.erb') do
    'test/integration/site_layout_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb') do
    integration_tests << 'test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb'
  end
  watch('app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb') do
    ['test/controllers/sessions_controller_test.rb',
     'test/integration/users_login_test.rb']
  end
  watch('app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb') do
    'test/integration/users_signup_test.rb'
  end
end

# Returns the integration tests corresponding to the given resource.
def integration_tests(resource = :all)
  if resource == :all
    Dir["test/integration/*"]
  else
    Dir["test/integration/#{resource}_*.rb"]
  end
end

# Returns the controller tests corresponding to the given resource.
def controller_test(resource)
  "test/controllers/#{resource}_controller_test.rb"
end

# Returns all tests for the given resource.
def resource_tests(resource)
  integration_tests(resource) << controller_test(resource)
end
```

This only seems to be happening with Rails 6. I have a similar app setup on Rails 5 and I'm not getting this error.

Comment: I shutdown the server, ran `spring stop` and got `Spring stopped.` Then ran `rails s` and got the same error. Is this something I should report as a bug with rails?

Comment: It seems it was already reported, take a look to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34912) issue.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. So does this mean the fix might be in the next version of rails? Seems like it was fixed in September and should have already been included in Rails 6, right?

Comment: See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32700#issuecomment-417645788 for a workaround

Comment: kobaltz adding that initializers/fixes.rb file mentioned did not fix it. I'm confused, if it's marked as an issue that has been fixed in the rails repository, which version of rails is it fixed for? It appears that it was fixed here https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33822/files. So has that just not shown up in a release yet? if so it's fine, I can wait, but just having difficulty figuring out how to connect that commit to releases of rails.